# RxJava: Unsubscribe async observable from within another async production

Tags: rx-java, kotlin

What is a best (clean) way to unsubscribe an async `Observable` wich is produced in a `flatMap` of another async one?
Say, I have a presentation that shows a chat list for user.
Each Chat item should present the latest message of itself.
Here is an original code to illustrate:

```
fun AsyncInsideAsync() {
    /**
     * A chat that 'transmits' latest message
     */
    class Chat(val name: Int) {
        val lastMessage: PublishSubject<String> = PublishSubject.create()

        fun postMessage(message: Int) {
            lastMessage.onNext("Chat: $name, Message: $message")
        }
    }

    // List of chats for user.
    val chats: PublishSubject<Chat> = PublishSubject.create()

    ///////////////////////////////////
    //        ORIGINAL SEQUENCE      //
    ///////////////////////////////////
    val sequence = chats.flatMap { it.lastMessage }

    val subscriber = TestSubscriber<String>()
    sequence.subscribe(subscriber)

    // User has single chat in a chat-list
    val chat1 = Chat(1)
    chats.onNext(chat1)

    // Someone posts a message in Chat 1
    chat1.postMessage(1)
    subscriber.assertValues(
            "Chat: 1, Message: 1"
    )

    // Someone posts another message
    chat1.postMessage(2)
    subscriber.assertValues(
            "Chat: 1, Message: 1",
            "Chat: 1, Message: 2"
    )

    // Chat 1 disappears FROM USER CHAT LIST, Chat 2 is created
    val chat2 = Chat(2)
    chats.onNext(chat2)

    // Someone posts a message to Chat 2
    chat2.postMessage(1)
    subscriber.assertValues(
            "Chat: 1, Message: 1",
            "Chat: 1, Message: 2",
            "Chat: 2, Message: 1"
    )

    // Someone out there posts a message to Chat 1 that is not visible to user anymore
    chat1.postMessage(3)

    // The answer looks like this 
    //      "Chat: 1, Message: 1",
    //      "Chat: 1, Message: 2",
    //      "Chat: 2, Message: 1",
    //      "Chat: 1, Message: 3"
    // Chat 1 is still subscribed and test fails
    subscriber.assertValues(
            "Chat: 1, Message: 1",
            "Chat: 1, Message: 2",
            "Chat: 2, Message: 1",
    )
}
```

What I came up to is using a subject (or shared observable) to brake a chain of internal subscriptions. But it looks weird:

```
    ///////////////////////////////////
    //        MODIFIED SEQUENCE      //
    ///////////////////////////////////
    val unsubscribe: PublishSubject<Boolean> = PublishSubject.create()
    val sequence = chats
            .doOnNext({ unsubscribe.onNext(true) })
            .doAfterTerminate({ unsubscribe.onNext(true) })
            .flatMap {
                it.lastMessage.takeUntil(unsubscribe)
            }
```

This approach works but looks frighteningly.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: For some reason, I don't think that this is a good match for Rx; perhaps you would do better if you modeled your use case with an event bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the comment

```
// Chat 1 disappears FROM USER CHAT LIST, Chat 2 is created
```

indicates that you'd like the current `Chat` (`chat1` in this case) to stop emitting when a new `Chat` is sent on `chats`, you can accomplish this with the `switchMap` operator.

```
val sequence = chats.switchMap { it.lastMessage }
```

From the ReactiveX documentation:

> RxJava also implements the switchMap operator. It behaves much like
>   flatMap, except that whenever a new item is emitted by the source
>   Observable, it will unsubscribe to and stop mirroring the Observable
>   that was generated from the previously-emitted item, and begin only
>   mirroring the current one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was obvious :)